# foreign key not recognised in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

According to [Dayle Rees](http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-relationships)

> All foreign key columns follow a similar naming convention. The singular form of the related model appended with _id.

Consider this migration:

```
class CreateTables extends Migration {
// ...
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('artists', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name',64);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('albums', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name',64);
        $table->integer('artist_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('artist_id')->references('id')->on('artists');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here are my eloquent models:

```
<?php
// Artist model
class Artist extends Eloquent {
    public function albums() {
        return $this->hasMany('Album');
    }
}

<?php
// Album model
class Album extends Eloquent {
    public function artists() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Artist');
    }
}
```

I used them like this:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $artist = new Artist;
    $artist->name = "Morbid Angel";
    $artist->save();
    $album = new Album;
    $album->name = "Altars of Madness";
    $album->artists()->associate($artist);
    $album->save();
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

This does not seem to work, according to the logs:

> [2015-06-09 06:01:12] production.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'artists_id' in 'field list''

But I did not create a `artists_id`. What does this mean? Shouldn't laravel find `artist_id` because it should be singular followed `by _id`?

Comment: How did you define your relationship. I guess it is a one to many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was your problem. You have named your relation `artists`, but it should be `artist`**. That's why it was looking for a column named `artists_id`.

You should define your relations as follow as it looks to me it is a One to Many.

In your `Artists` Model

```
public function albums()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Album');
}
```

In your `Albums` Model

```
public function artist()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Artist');
}
```

Then try your code.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $artist = new Artist;
    $artist->name = "Morbid Angel";
    $artist->save();

    $album = new Album;
    $album->name = "Altars of Madness";

    $artist->albums()->save($album);

    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Comment: I see, your models are fine. Did you try see the change I made to the insertion part of your code in my answer. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I used your insertion code and it work. Why is that? And I used the name artists in the function because the book uses plural for the albumsfunctions. They said it doesn't matter what name you gave to the function of the model.

Comment: I guess it does matter because I think that name is used derive the key name of the relation. The error was throwing because it was looking for an `artists_id` instead of `artist_id`. And another thing if you are calling `associate` you need to save your object first.
If my answer helped you could you mark it as answered. Sad that omeone has downvoted my answer. :(

Comment: It's fine. Cheers.  :)

Comment: actually the only code that made it work, regardless of what name we give to the model functions is your code here: $artist->albums()->save($album); Can you explain how this code works and why the code in the book is wrong?

Comment: @morbidCode For `hasOne`/`hasMany` relations, the name of the function doesn't matter. However, for `belongsTo` relations, the name of the foreign key, if not supplied in the second parameter, is derived from the name of the relationship. You can either change the name of the function to be singular, provide the name of the field in the second parameter, or even provide the name of the relationship in the fourth parameter (`return $this->belongsTo('Artist', null, null, 'artist');`

Comment: I did it like that because it was the natural way. There are artists and they release albums. That's why I first created an artist, then created an album and saved it. When saving a relation laravel will automatically insert the related id and save it. You were doing it the other way. It's fine and you can do it that way. Only error was the name. Your approach should work after renaming the relation or specifying the key. Try it and see. Please disregard this line **you need to save your object first.** in my previous comment as it is not necessary.

Comment: @chanafdo Your relationship methods are missing the `return`s.

Comment: Ooops! Forgot that. Thanks @patricus. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your artist model try `return $this->hasMany('Album', 'artist_id');`

Comment: Of course you can override it, but according to the book the default is artist_id, so we're not suppose to override it.